# FlowDocument BreakPageBefore property not working on Table Block

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

So I'm dynamically creating a FlowDocument by using code (based on this MSDN article on [How to build a table programatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753342(v=vs.110).aspx)).

The FlowDocument contains a number of blocks including paragraphs and tables. The tables being generated are of varying sizes and some are nested amongst other blocks.  If a table can't fit on the remaining space on a page, I want to start that table at the beginning of the next page.

I am doing this by recording the current page when creating a particular block and then when the table has been finished, if I am on a new page, I set the *BreakPageBefore* property to true. Something like this:

```
foreach (var item in Data)
{
    Table table = new Table();
    flowDoc.Blocks.Add(table);
    paginatorSource.DocumentPaginator.ComputePageCount();
    pagecount = paginatorSource.DocumentPaginator.PageCount;

    //do some work populating the table details...
    TableColumn t = new TableColumn(); //etc...

    paginatorSource.DocumentPaginator.ComputePageCount();
    int newPagecount = paginatorSource.DocumentPaginator.PageCount;

    if (newPagecount != pagecount)
    { 
        //The table has spanned a new page so set the page break!
        table.BreakPageBefore = true;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't appear to work.  However, if I wrap the table in a *Section* and set the *BreakPageBefore* on the section, it works fine.  Also, If I have a *Paragraph* just before the table, I can set the *BreakPageBefore* on the *Paragraph* and that also works fine.

I have tried creating a simple FlowDocument that just has a bunch of repeating tables and that doesn't make any difference and I still have to wrap them in a Section.

They all inherit from *Block* So why won't it work on the *Table* directly?

Comment: Does it not call table.BreakPageBefore = true; or is it just not honored?

Comment: The call is being made but it is not being honoured.  I tested with the call in a for each loop, to make sure it was being called on every block (when there were only Table blocks in the flow doc) and it just appears to be ignored.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a bug.  Given you have a work around (section) I would just do that.

Comment: Yes I have a workaround, so it is no big problem. It sounds like a bug to me, but I just wanted to check to see if anyone else had it working...

Comment: @Jason I'd say add your workaround as an answer so I can upvote it.